# How to update data in supabase having one to many relation?

Tags: supabase, supabase-database

I am working on a smaller project. I have two tables e.g. properties and agents. One property can have many agents. How can I update data in both tables using one query?
Here is the link to update data in postgres [How I can update one to many relation in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60337152/how-i-can-update-one-to-many-relation-in-postgres)

Comment: You can probably generate a function similar to the answer there. Then call this function [using RPC](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/rpc)

Answer (score 0):

Supabase uses postgrest under the hood for the RESTful api, currently the [suggested solution](https://github.com/PostgREST/postgrest/issues/818) there is to write an [rpc() function](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/rpc) and call that.

Alternatively, since Supabase is *just* PostgreSQL, you always have the option of connecting directly using any postgres client and using the postgres solution you mentioned in your question.